# How to attract "Curve guide" particles with a Secondary force field?

Tags: particles, force-fields

For a asteroid simulation ,some particles (spheres) on **a curve guide need to be attracted to the centre(magnetic force field).**

However,after setting the mass of particles to the lowest value(0.1) and increasing the strength of the magnetic field (1000+) there is no impact on the simulation.

Adjusting Force field weights even by a little ,causes the particles to go completely haywire.

How to achieve this simulation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: not sure it will work, you may need to switch your curve from Curve Guide to Force, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYHOV3bVIG0

Comment: thanks, this might work by having  2 simulations , one for the inner slower  motion (closer to centre with force ) and the other providing  faster perimeter motion(with curve ).